# Search through N-ary tree and return Node

Tags: java, tree

I need to find a given node, then return it or null if it doesn't find it.

I've tried this but it returns null:

```
public NodoN<T> buscarNodo(T dato, NodoN<T> nodo){
        if(nodo != null) {
            // Root is dummy and is null
            if (nodo.dato != null && nodo.dato.equals(dato)){
               return nodo;
            } else {
                int cantHijos = nodo.nodos.size();
                ArrayList<NodoN<T>> nodosHijos = nodo.nodos;
                NodoN<T> nodoEncontrado;
                for (int i = 0; i < cantHijos; i++) {
                    nodoEncontrado = buscarNodo(dato, nodosHijos.get(i));
                    if(nodoEncontrado.dato.equals(dato)){
                       return nodo;
                    }
                }
             }
        }
        return null;
}
```

When looking at the debugger, it correctly finds the one that I want but then keeps going in the loop and returns null.

NodoN class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NodoN<T> {
    T dato;
    Integer tMax;
    ArrayList<NodoN<T>> nodos;

    public NodoN(T dato, Integer tMax){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.tMax = tMax;
        nodos = new ArrayList<NodoN<T>>();
    }

    public void agregar(NodoN<T> nodo){
        if (nodos.size()<tMax){
            nodos.add(nodo);
        }else{
            nodos.get(0).agregar(nodo);
        }

    }

    String inOrder(boolean ingnorarRaiz){
        String ret = "";

        if (!ingnorarRaiz){
            ret =ret + dato.toString() + ",";
        }

        for (int i=0;i<nodos.size();i++){
            ret = ret + nodos.get(i).inOrder(false);
        }

        return ret;

    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "When looking at the debugger, it correctly finds the one that I want but then keeps going in the loop and returns null"?  How can it return null if it already found the one you wanted?

Comment: @jiaweizhang I mean I am failing in returning the node when I find it. Execution should stop and return that, it's because of it being recursive, I always had problems with it lol

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) on a custom class, you should implement it (aswell as [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)).